# How to control numbers of rows and columns using facet grid

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet

I want to create a facet grid-type plot so I only have labels for the categorical axis in the left-most column of a grid of plots.  It looks like facet_grid is the best tool to do this but I cannot work out how to control the rows and columns options to get the desired result.

For example, the script below using facet_wrap produces a n x n plot but I only want labels in the left-most column

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(Cat_1 = factor(rep(c("A", "A", "A","A", "B", "B","B", "B","C","C", "C", "C"), 4)),
                 Cat_2 = factor (rep(c("W", "X", "Y", "Z", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", "W", "X","Y", "Z"),4)),
                 Value = runif(48, min = 1, max = 5))


ggplot(data = df, aes(x = Cat_1, y = Value)) +
  geom_point() +
  coord_flip() +
  facet_wrap(~ Cat_2, scales = "free", ncol = 2) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank())
```

[image: facet_wrap with 2 x 2 layout]

When I can change to facet_grid in the code below:

```
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = Cat_1, y = Value)) +
  geom_point() +
  coord_flip() +
  facet_grid(~ Cat_2, scales = "free") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank())
```

This ensures that there are only labels in the left-most column but with no 2 x 2 layout

[image: facet_grid 1 x 4 layout]

Is there a way to control facet_grid's columns and rows or alternatively I'm looking for a  method to control facet_wrap so it only prepares the category labels on the left-most column?

Comment: Do you mean this: change `scales = free` to `scales = free_x`!

Comment: Or just leave out the `scales` argument altogether, unless it's required for your real data?

Comment: Yes I need the scales argument for the real data

Comment: If you specify `scales = "free"` then `ggplot` assumes that each axis scale is, potentially, independent and optimized for the values in each facet. So you cannot have a common y-axis across all plots if you use `facet_wrap` with scales. You might be able to achieve what you want using _e.g._ `cowplot` or `patchwork` packages.

Comment: Really I only need to have the numeric values on a free scale ... if I used scales = "free_y" is there then a way to control the layout?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect there's an addin that helps here, but one approach would be to map your columns to the row and column you want them to appear in, and feed that to `facet_grid`, with a layer added to note the original `Cat_2` in each facet.

```
library(dplyr)
df |>
  mutate(row = if_else(Cat_2 %in% c("W", "X"), 1, 2),
         col = if_else(Cat_2 %in% c("W", "Y"), 1, 2)) %>%
ggplot(data = ., aes(x = Cat_1, y = Value)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_text(aes(x = Inf, y = -Inf, label = Cat_2),
            hjust = -0.5, vjust = 1.5,
            data = . %>% distinct(Cat_2, .keep_all = TRUE)) +
  coord_flip() +
  facet_grid(row~col) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank())
```

[image]